# Parse doesn't work in app release version, but works on simulator or when installed on device via xcode

Tags: ios, logging, heroku, parse-platform

I have a parse deployed in Heroku for my app. When I run app in simulator or on my test device after installing via xcode, everything works fine. I can fetch data and see images downloaded on initial view controller. But, whenever app is on app store review or being installed via Test Flight, Parse just stops working. I can't fetch any data and app becomes almost useless.
The code looks like this:

```
class ListOfCategoriesViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var categories: [DisplayCategory] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // loader
    let spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
    spinner.center = self.view.center
    spinner.startAnimating()
    view.addSubview(spinner)

    //setting text
    self.title = "Explore"

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Category")


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (result: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.categories = result as? [DisplayCategory] ?? []
        spinner.stopAnimating() // loader stops here and code below never executes


        for category in self.categories {

            category.imageCategoryFile?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!, scale: 1.0)
                category.imageCategory = image

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DisplayCategory class looks like this:

```
class DisplayCategory: PFObject, PFSubclassing {


@NSManaged var imageCategoryFile: PFFile?
@NSManaged var titleCategory: String?
var imageCategory: UIImage?

static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Category"
}
```

Any ideas what might cause this issue here? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was trivial. I needed to register subclass in AppDelegate and call it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:

So, it now looks like this in AppDelegate:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    configureParse()

    return true

}

func configureParse() {
    DisplayCategory.registerSubclass()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Just checked. I have this in my info.plist. Any other ideas what might cause the problem?